Как собрать данные по отзывам на Yandex Карты?
Я начинаю использовать Яндекс.Карты для проекта, в котором мне необходимо собирать информацию об отзывах, оставленных клиентами. Я написал несколько скриптов, но ни один из них не может обойти API Яндекса, поэтому скрипты не возвращают ничего. Существует ли обходной путь для этого? Как можно получить данные с Яндекс.Карт, не приобретая API, для сбора информации об отзывах? Если у вас есть какие-либо полезные ссылки или советы, я был бы рад ознакомиться с ними. Думаю, кто-то должен иметь обходной путь для этого.
